# A probability question regarding combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics

From a class of $300$ students, three are selected at random to receive three identical prizes. Of the students, $200$ are from department $A$, $60$ from department $B$ and $40$ from department $C$.

1. Find the probability that the three winners come from different departments.
2. Find the probability that all three winners come from the same department.
3. Suppose that all three are from the same department. Compute the probability that they are all from department $A$.

Here is my attempt. I am not sure if this is correct.

1. $P(\text{different departments})=3!\binom{200}{1}\binom{60}{1}\binom{40}{1}$ or $3!\frac{200}{300}\times \frac{60}{299} \times\frac{40}{298}$?
2. $P(\text{same department})=\dfrac{\binom{200}{1}+\binom{60}{1}+\binom{40}{1}}{\binom{300}{3}}= \dfrac{3}{44551}$.
3. $\begin{align} P(\text{from department A}|\text{same department}) & = \dfrac{P(\text{from department A}) P(\text{same department})}{P(\text{same department})} \\
   & = \dfrac{\binom{200}{1} \frac{3}{4451}}{\frac{3}{4451}} \\
   &=\binom{200}{1}. \end{align}$

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: I am interpreting the problem to mean that the three winners must be different people.

Unfortunately all three proposed solutions are incorrect.

There are ${300 \choose 3}$ subsets of size 3.  This will be the denominator for the first two questions.  In the first question, the numerator is ${200\choose 1}{60\choose 1}{40 \choose 1}$.  We want one of our three winners to be from department $A$, one from $B$, and one from $C$; these three choices are made independently, so we use the multiplication principle.

The numerator of the second question is ${200\choose 3}+{60\choose 3}+{40\choose 3}$.  There are three types of subsets, those entirely from $A$, those entirely from $B$, and those entirely from $C$.  These are disjoint subsets of ${300\choose 3}$, so we use the addition principle.  To count the subsets entirely from $A$, we need to pick 3 winners.

The denominator in the third question is the same as the numerator of the second question, since now we are restricting to only those triplets that are from a single department, which the numerator from the second question was counting.  The numerator of the third question is ${200\choose 3}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well explained.